# Any efficient way to calculate the sum of harmonic series upto nth term? 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + --- + 1/n =?

Tags: sum, mathematical-optimization, series

Is there any formula for this series "1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + --- + 1/n = ?" I think it is a harmonic number in a form of sum(1/k) for k = 1 to n.

Comment: This belongs on e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not really - not advanced enough.

Comment: Well, it's not programming related – it's math related.

Comment: @duffymo: Actually, math.stackexchange.com sounds like a perfect home for this question -- it's explicitly for "math at any level", unlike, say, mathoverflow.net.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will visit that site. The answer of this question will help me solve a prob in Algorithm, which is computer-related though

Comment: @Jim Lewis - Thanks for the heads up.  I didn't realize that there were two math URLs now.

Comment: Integrate 1/x from 1 to n. Therefore it gives [ ln(x) + c ] as the answer.

Comment: Why not move it instead of closing it? Search engines still link to these closed questions and it's generally unproductive and unwelcoming to new users to treat them like this.

Answer (score 10):

As it is the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) summed up to `n`, you're looking for the `n`th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), approximately given by `γ + ln[n]`, where `γ` is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant).

For small `n`, just calculate the sum directly:

```
double H = 0;
for(double i = 1; i < (n+1); i++) H += 1/i;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you question correctly, reading this should help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to look at it:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1/j,+j%3D1+to+n

Answer (score 0):

```
function do(int n) 
{
    if(n==1)
        return n;

    return 1/n + do(--n); 
}
```

Comment: While recursive solutions look elegant, in this case it's inappropriate.

Comment: If the number is large enough you will get a stack overflow, or you will be adding basically zero, and not really changing the value much.

Comment: I figured he'd be using small sample numbers